# Google Sheets: E-Mail Notification When Named

Tags: notifications, google-sheets

My work team shares access to a shared Google Sheet; it's a task log with a responsible person for each item.
I'd like to set it up so that if someone adds a new task to be completed and names someone specifically who's responsible for completing it, the named person receives an e-mail notification letting them know they've got a new task to do.

I've looked through the archives and even consulted our IT guys - but am still none the wiser!
Any help **very** much appreciated.

Thanks very much!

Josh

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this function is native, all you need is:

1. make new comment, go to `Insert → Comment` or press `Ctrl + Alt + M`
2. and enter '+', then user email of responsible person.

look for [more info here](https://apps.google.com/learning-center/products/sheets/create-dynamic-project-plans/)